# Ostream from multiple classes

Tags: c++, ostream

I seem to be getting the Error C2440: 'return' cannot convert from 'LinkList' to 'Tray *'. What i'm trying to do is add the output of a second class to that of the customer class. So if i was to call a method such as whoIsEating() i could easily get a list of who, where and what. I had an idea of using 'friend' but i'm quite unsure on that.

Customer.h

```
class Customer
{
private:
    int tableNumber;
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    LinkList<Tray> *myTray;
public:
    Customer();
    Customer(std::string sFirstName, std::string sLastName,
        int sTableNumber,
        LinkList<Tray> *myTray = new LinkList<Tray>());
    ~Customer(void);

    int gettableNumber();
    Tray* getTray(void);
```

Customer.cpp

```
Tray* Customer::getTray()
{
    return *myTray;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Customer& customer)
{
    output << customer.getFirstName() << " " << customer.getLastName() << endl
        << customer.gettableNumber() << endl
        << (*customer.getTray()) << endl; //Edit: Fixed this
    return output;
```

Tray.cpp

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Tray& tray)
{
    output << "Drink: " << tray.getdrink() << endl;
    output << "Food: " << tray.getfood() << endl;
    return output;
}
```

Suspected output would be like

Name: John Smith

Table Number: 12

Meal Details:

Drink: Tea

Food: Fish & Chips

Comment: What in heck is `AccountManager`? No mention of that in your code. Please present a real http://sscce.org

Comment: `<< customer.getTray() endl;` looks fishy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've had this other project in my head while typing that out i didn't realise i did that. Also I wish i could provide one but the thing is it doesn't compile.

Comment: The `getTray` function returns a pointer, the output operator overload is for a reference.

Comment: Please don't down vote, I really need help with this.

Comment: @Melky: "I wish I could provide one" You _can_, and you shall!

Answer (score 2):

In your customer.cpp file you have getTray returning a pointer to a Tray, and you pass out the myTray instance variable:

```
Tray* Customer::getTray()
{
    return *myTray;
}
```

However, in your customer class you have have already defined myTray to be a LinkedList

```
class Customer
{
    ...
    LinkList<Tray> *myTray; << here
```

You need to return a pointer to a Tray so you probably want to do something more like:

```
Tray* Customer::getTray()
{
    return &(myTray->first());
}
```

Comment: That seems to cause "IntelliSense: expression must be an lvalue or a function designator"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It just does, I'm not sure why.

Comment: I think that rather than passing references around, you should probably just pass value objects, as this will make your code easier to understand.

Comment: So, rather than have `LinkedList<Tray> *myTray = new LinkedList<Tray>()`, add a LinkedList<Tray> myTray object to the class. I you need the option of assigning the contents of another list on construction, than create two constructors, one without and the other with the list to assign. And from the getTray method, just return a Tray value object not a Tray* pointer.

Answer (score 0):

### You posted

```
template<typename T>
class LinkList {
public:
    LinkList();
    ~LinkList();
    void insert(T); //Insert new node in order
    void print(); //Outputs contents
    int getSize();
    void target(T);
    Node<T>* search(T); //Search for value in link list 
                        //and returns pointer to value
    Node<T> *startingPtr;
    Node<T> *endPtr;
private:
    bool isEmpty();
    void insertStart(T); //insert before first node
    void insertEnd(T); //insert after last node
    void insertNext(T);
    void insertBefore(T);
};

template<typename T>
class Node {
    friend class LinkList<T>;
public: 
    T getData();
    Node(T);
    Node* nextPtr;
private:
    T data;
    Node* prevPtr;
};
```

### Problem

The `LinkedList` class doesn't expose the data that you want.

You want to return a pointer to a `Tray`, a.k.a. `Tray*`:

```
Tray* Customer::getTray()
```

...but the object you have is a pointer to a `LinkedList<Tray>`:

```
LinkList<Tray> *myTray;
```

The `LinkedList` class gives you access to `Node<Tray>*`, e.g.:

```
Node<T> *startingPtr;
```

...and the `Node` class gives you access to a `Tray` object via the `getData` method:

```
T getData();
```

...but unfortunately you want a `Tray*`, and it's not straightforward to get a `Tray*` from all that.  (The problem is that `getData` returns a temporary object that will disappear soon, so if you take the address of that object to get a `Tray*`, you'll have a pointer that will soon point at garbage.)

### Solution

One workaround would be to have `getTray` return a `Node<Tray>*`, which you do have access to, e.g.:

```
Node<Tray>* Customer::getTray()
{
    return myTray->startingPtr;
}

// note that this assumes that the customer has at least one tray in it's list
ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Customer& customer)
{
    output << customer.getFirstName() << " " << customer.getLastName() << endl
        << customer.gettableNumber() << endl
        << customer.getTray()->getData() << endl;
    return output;
}

// note the added 'const', which means tray.getdrink() and tray.getfood()
// will have to be const member methods
ostream& operator << (ostream& output, const Tray& tray) 
{
    output << "Drink: " << tray.getdrink() << endl;
    output << "Food: " << tray.getfood() << endl;
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of that solution, please?